# Hat dash stats not matching the leaderboard

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

When I finish a game in Hat Dash, it says:

> Games played: 239 over 152.3 minutes

When I look on the all-time leaderboard, it says:

> | User | Minutes | Total Games |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | kylejrp | 130.92 | 133 |

I'm aware that games played before you've earned the privilege don't count, but this isn't the case for me. What could be the reason for the 20+ minute discrepancy and 100+ missing games?

Some ideas of what it *might* be:

- Leaving the game open too long and something time sensitive fails

  - Something with the anti-cheat checking start/end times?
  - Something with my client using an older version of the game and it fails the server side anti-cheat check?
- Playing on multiple devices
- Playing on a smartphone
- Playing while the game is laggy (I've seen some of my games have the similar time but wildly different score)

Comment: Also yes I'm aware that I've played way too much hat dash someone send help before all I can see is unicorns 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own stats include all of the games that you recorded. The overall leaderboard only includes games that have not been excluded by the anti-cheating system based on [different heuristics].

Comment: I don't think I've done any actions that I expected to be excluded by the anti-cheat  I've played the game as intended so far  I know you can't explain the heuristics but I'm wondering if there's something unintentional that's throwing away some of my games

Comment: It looks like *all* of my scores have been removed from the leaderboard, I'm assuming that I might have triggered the anti-cheat and got banned, but I'm not sure how because I've been playing it above board  I would love to work together to figure out what's going wrong! Feel free to ping me in the winter bash chat.